# Run java file from other working path under Linux

Tags: java, linux

I have following simple java application that opens a file to read. I have compiled it into run.jar file then copy run.jar file under  `/var/project`  also copied file.txt near it
When I type `"java -cp run.jar com.text.FileMain"` 
everything is fine

However when changed my directory to lets say `"/tmp"` then type following command, I am having an error "could not find `file.txt` file."
Actualy it is expected result. What can I do to run this application without changing code  since it is an API and I am not allowed to change it.

is it possible?

```
$ java -cp /var/project/run.jar com.test.FileMain
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:55)
        at com.test.FileMain.main(FileMain.java:20)
```

$ pwd
/tmp

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        // print out the list
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: if any of the answers helped you should mark them as right. why ? see the [faq]

Comment: Answers shows me that there is no solution but code changes.

Comment: How does making a soft link or using a script constitute a code change? or why do neither of those work for you?

Comment: all these are workaround solution. If there are many points where application can be started, there will be many soft links

Comment: dont know how you can expect a more generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the code using a script.

In script cd to the **/var/project** folder then give java command. after script runs you should be back in /tmp dir. but java will run off /var/project and thus find the file.

Sample source of script

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/project
java -cp /var/project/run.jar com.test.FileMain
```

Save to '/var/project/run.sh' give permissions to execute and should be fine

to run it from prompt

> ```
> $ /var/project/run.sh
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a soft link to file.txt in your /tmp

```
ln -s /var/project/file.txt /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

with

```
  File file = new File("./file.txt");
```

Comment: I don't think so, The best choice is to specify the file full path in main arguments

Answer (score 0):

Files have a location in the directory namespace.   "file.txt" means this file in the current directory.  When you cd /tmp "file.txt" isn't there.   To fix pass the fully qualified path into main rather than hardcode "file.txt"  So you pass "/tmp/file.txt" into your code and all should be well

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the directory of the file too or only the jar. As per the code the file should be present in the directory from where the java program is being executed and not the path of the jar, anyway since you cannot change the code, you code add some script to move the file to the required path before execution.